# Проверка формы на валидность с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Хочу сделать проверку формы на jQuery или JavaScript.

Вот сама форма:

```
<form id="create_account" action="registration_new.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset id="singup">
        <legend>Создайте новый аккаунт</legend>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="username"><i class="icon-user"></i>Логин:</label>
                    <input id="username" type="text" autofocus name="username" required placeholder="John" tabindex="1">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="email"><i class="icon-envelope"></i>Email:</label>
                    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="user@example.com" required autocomplete="off" tabindex="2">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="password"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i>Пароль:</label>
                    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="" autocomplete="off" required placeholder="8-10 символов" tabindex="3">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="password_confirm"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i>Повторите пароль:</label>
                    <input id="password_confirm" type="password" name="password_confirm" value="" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Введите пароль еще раз" tabindex="4">
                </li>
                <li>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="5"><span><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></span>Зарегистрироваться</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Сейчас есть очень простая проверка на jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#create_account:submit').click(function(e){
        var allOk = true;
        $(':text, :password').each(function(){
            var stl = '2px solid ';
            if($(this).val()) {
                stl += 'green';
            } else {
                stl += 'red';
                allOk = false;
            }
            $(this).css('border', stl);
            });
            !allOk && e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Нужно сделать проверку email на валидность. И как можно сделать, чтобы ошибки отображались красиво рядом с полем формы, где произошла ошибка?

Comment: Плюс я так понял, что нужно по-убирать везде required, а то jQuery не работает!

Comment: Извините, но: 

 - [***`Инструмент`*** для валидации][1]
 - [Регулярное выражение для **`E-Mail`**][2]


  [1]: http://bit.ly/KCfsr7
  [2]: http://bit.ly/KCfLCp

Comment: Не много не корректно задал вопрос - как в jQuery использовать регулярное выражение? var pattern = new RegExp ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Плагин для jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: Пробовал использовать этот плагин, но почему-то не заработало ничего ;((

Comment: По нему достаточно документации, и под твои задачи он идеально подходит. Выложи код, который у тебя не работает, посмотрим, что не так.